# Symfony4 swiftmailer doesnt exist in container

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer, symfony4

im having troubles sending an email in symfony4. I'm following [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/email.html) so I installed swiftmailer using `composer req mailer` command. My method looks like this

```
public function sendAccountActivationLink(Array $data, \Swift_Mailer $mailer)
{
    $message = (new \Swift_Message('Hello Email'))
        ->setFrom('myemail@gmail.com')
        ->setTo($data['email'])
        ->setBody(
            $this->renderView(
                'mails/registration.html.twig',
                ['data' => $data]
            ),
            'text/html'
        )
    ;

    $mailer->send($message);
}
```

it says that `Swift_Mailer` class requires an transport interface, but there is nothing about it in the docs.

I tried to call mailer through container

```
$this->get('mailer')->send($message);
```

but it says `Call to a member function has() on null`
In addition ill paste my yml config

```
swiftmailer:
    url: '%env(MAILER_URL)%'
    spool: { type: 'memory' }
    transport: smtp
    username: myemail@gmail.com
    password: password
    host: localhost
    port: false
```

and the mailer url

```
MAILER_URL=gmail://myemail@gmail.com:password@localhost
```

Comment: Is sendAccountActivationLink a controller action?  Seems a bit strange to be sending it a Array $data parameter.  I suspect you are calling it directly and just new'ing the mailer instance?

Comment: Yes it is. I created a EmailController, because I don't really know where should I put a class that cointains methods that go over sending emails and I dont want that code in the place where the main action is happening(i.e. registration) Why is it strange? I need multiple variables in the email view so I send the array, I know I should make use of ArrayCollection, but that doesn't matter now.

Comment: It would be strange if it were a controller action.  But it's not.  Going to need to spend some effort on understanding services and dependency injections.  Start with the [service container](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html).

Comment: @Cerad yeah, i moved the code from the controller and i dont see the error. Will have to catch up on the services! Thanks!